# GLOBAL UpPer CaSe TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can I globally convert all text in the databases to UPPER CASE. 
This is only test data but lots of it 20,000,000 rows 145 columns that are( 'char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar')

Does anyone have ideas on how to do this...? 
I know you can use UPPER

```
Update table
set col1 = UPPER(col1)
```

But this limits it to an individual column
But how do I create a cursor using the information schema views and loop through all the character type columns to determine which to update:

```
select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar')
```

I have no FKs  in the tables
Thanks

Comment: Should be easy to hack one of the global search and replace scripts to do this. Example http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_search_and_replace.htm

Comment: Why do you want to do this. It sounds like you want to "speed" up case insensitive comparison. Also note that this is extremely tricky to do on non-Latin character sets.

Comment: It is to create a xml data set for cobol that is only upper case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if its a hacky one-off just make the query spit out some copy/pasteable SQL;

```
SELECT 'update [' + p1.table_name + '] set ' +
(SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by column_name) > 1 THEN ',' ELSE '' END
    + '[' + column_name + ']=upper([' + column_name + '])'
    FROM information_schema.columns p2 
    WHERE p2.table_name = p1.table_name and p2.data_type in ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar')
    ORDER BY table_name
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS blah
FROM information_schema.columns p1
    WHERE p1.data_type in ('char', 'nchar', 'varchar', 'nvarchar')
GROUP BY table_name;
```

which would spit out;

```
update [Tbl] set [F1]=upper([F1]),[F2]=upper([F2])
```